# Python Pandas Pass Argument to Group by two or more columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm trying to use a function to group by several columns by passing the columns into the function but I can't seem to get the correct syntax and I keep getting errors.
The code works when passing one column to group.
Any advice would be most welcome.

The code is:

```
groupby = (['HxHorse', 'Jockey', 'Trainer'])
avgof = 'Hrs'
avgcol = 'Hrsmean'
colname = 'Hrs'
df_racecard = getagg(df_racecard, df_hrsall, groupby, avgof, avgcol, colname)
```

And the function is:

```
def getagg(df_racecard, df_hrsall, groupby, avgof, avgcol, colname):    
    hrs_agg = df_hrsall.groupby([groupby], as_index=False).agg({avgof: ['mean']})
    hrs_agg.columns = ["".join(x) for x in hrs_agg.columns.ravel()]
    hrs_agg.rename(columns = {avgcol:colname}, inplace = True)        
    df_racecard = pd.merge(left=df_racecard, right=hrs_agg[[groupby, colname]], left_on='Horse', right_on='HxHorse', how='left')
    df_racecard = df_racecard.drop(['HxHorse'], axis=1)
    return df_racecard
```

The function works with :

```
groupby = 'HxHorse'
avgof = 'Hrs'
avgcol = 'Hrsmean'
colname = 'Hrs'
df_racecard = getagg(df_racecard, df_hrsall, groupby, avgof, avgcol, colname)
```

It seems to fail at:

```
df_hrsall.groupby([groupby]
```

I've tried variations of `groupby = (['HxHorse', 'Jockey', 'Trainer'])` such as `groupby = [['HxHorse'], ['Jockey'], ['Trainer']]`

Comment: You can try `groupby = ['HxHorse', 'Jockey', 'Trainer']` and then `hrs_agg = df_hrsall.groupby(groupby, as_index=False)...` (without the `[]`).

Comment: Thanks Shaido.  That seems to work as the code steps through the "groupby" ok.  However, the merge now fails.  I tried changing to "...merge(left=df_racecard, right=hrs_agg[groupby, colname], left_on='Horse'...."  but the error is "(['HxHorse', 'Jockey', 'Trainer'], 'Hrs')' is an invalid key."

Comment: Maybe `hrs_agg[groupby + [colname]]` could work.

Comment: @Shaido. Thanks again - I think I don't need to merge on '[groupby, colname]'  so I can just merge on the whole df 'pd.merge(left=df_racecard, right=hrs_agg,'.